# Which audio format would be the best?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, avaudioplayer, openal

I was using AVAudioPlayer to play multiple audio clips back to back but there was always a small silence between tracks and then i came to know of Finch, a library which uses OpenAL to play audio. with this the silence problem seems to be solved theoretically but then i found that it doesn't play m4a or any other compressed formats.

Now i am looking for an uncompressed audio format which would have relatively less file size (though uncompressed means that all of them should have almost same size) and a method to convert, i am also googling on afconvert in a mean while.

Answer (score 2):

CAF files work great for this. I've built an application that loops audio files, and I was impressed with the relatively small file size.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254080/converting-audio-to-caf-format-for-playback-on-iphone-using-openal) for more info on converting to CAF.

Comment: i tried and got:
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 fail.m4a fail.caf
Error: output channel layout has wrong number of channels (-1)