# XCode crashes when adding .m4a file to resources

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, m4a

I created my own small .m4a file with GarageBand, for use in my app on the iPhone. Everytime I try to Add existing file, XCode crashes when I select the .m4a file.
The file itself will play nicely in QuickTime Player and iTunes.

Any workarounds?

Comment: works fine for me... are you up-to-date with the latest version and what not?

Comment: Yep, Mac Mini has the very latest versions of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the workaround: put the .m4a file into a directory and "Add existing file" that directory to the project. That works, both the directory and the .m4a file in that directory are now part of the project.

Big XCode bug if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why Xcode would be crashing, but you might try [converting the audio file to the recommended format for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254080/converting-audio-to-caf-format-for-playback-on-iphone-using-openal).

Comment: Well, I tried that before, but I get the infamous "Error: output channel layout has wrong number of channels (-1)".
Thanks anyway, I'll see if I can somehow convert the m4a into something else.

Comment: Alas, same result when adding an .aif file: XCode crashes as soon as I try to add it (after the selection of the file, but before the dialog that asks about referencing or copying).