# AudioServicesPlayAlertSound not playing custom sound during application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I hope someone else has an insight into this problem...

I am trying to play a custom sound that is loaded into my app's resources. I created the sound using the afconvert tool, as recommended in the Converting audio to [CAF format for playback on iPhone using OpenAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254080/converting-audio-to-caf-format-for-playback-on-iphone-using-openal/255151#255151) thread. The specific command executed to produce my custom sound file is:

```
afconvert ~/Desktop/moof.au ~/Desktop/moof.caf -d ima4 -f caff -v
```

When I run my app on a test device (iPhone 5, iOS 7.0; or iPhone 4, iOS 6.1.3) and send a push notification containing the name of my custom sound file, the device vibrates but no sound plays.

Here's where it gets a little weird... If I set a breakpoint at the start of the method that plays the sound, and single-step through the code, the device plays the custom sound and vibrates in response to the push notification!

Here's the code in question:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    // If the app is running and receives a remote notification, the app calls this method to process
    // the notification payload. Your implementation of this method should use the app state to take an
    // appropriate course of action.

    ALog(@"push data package: %@", userInfo);
    NSDictionary *payload = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSNumber *badgeNumber = [payload objectForKey:@"badge"];
    NSString *soundName = [payload objectForKey:@"sound"];

    // app is in foreground
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        ALog(@"active");
        if (badgeNumber) {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [badgeNumber integerValue];
        }
        [self playPushNotificationAlertSound:soundName];
    }
    // app is in background
    else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        ALog(@"background");
        if (badgeNumber) {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [badgeNumber integerValue];
        }
        [self playPushNotificationAlertSound:soundName];
    }
    // app was launched from inactive state
    else if ((application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)) {
        ALog(@"inactive");
        if (badgeNumber) {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [badgeNumber integerValue];
        }
    }
}

- (void)playPushNotificationAlertSound:(NSString *)soundName
{
    ALog(@"soundName = '%@'", soundName);

    if (![soundName isEqualToString:@"default"]) {

        NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:soundName withExtension:@"caf"];

        if (soundURL) {
            CFURLRef soundFileURLRef = (__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL;
            SystemSoundID soundFileObject = 0;
            OSStatus status = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);
            if (status == kAudioServicesNoError) {
                AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(soundFileObject);
                AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundFileObject);
            }
            ALog(@"soundFileURLRef = %@", soundFileURLRef);
            ALog(@"soundFileObject = %i, status = %i", (unsigned int)soundFileObject, (int)status);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the console log without breakpoints active, and no custom sound plays:

```
2013-09-22 11:02:40.123 MyAppUnderDevelopment[2489:60b] push data package: {
    "_" = BlyZ4SOYEeOEc5DiugJ6IA;
    aps =     {
        alert = "Test #1";
        badge = 1;
        sound = moof;
    };
}
2013-09-22 11:02:40.124 MyAppUnderDevelopment[2489:60b] active
2013-09-22 11:02:40.136 MyAppUnderDevelopment[2489:60b] soundName = 'moof'
2013-09-22 11:02:40.138 MyAppUnderDevelopment[2489:60b] soundFileURLRef = file:///var/mobile/Applications/31785684-2EFA-4FEB-95F3-3A6B82B16A4A/MyAppUnderDevelopment.app/moof.caf
2013-09-22 11:02:40.139 MyAppUnderDevelopment[2489:60b] soundFileObject = 4100, status = 0
```

And the console log with breakpoint active, single-stepping, and the sound plays:

```
2013-09-22 11:03:29.891 MyAppUnderDevelopment[2489:60b] push data package: {
    "_" = "I_yGQCOYEeO515DiugJkgA";
    aps =     {
        alert = "Test #2";
        badge = 2;
        sound = moof;
    };
}
2013-09-22 11:03:29.892 MyAppUnderDevelopment[2489:60b] active
2013-09-22 11:03:33.752 MyAppUnderDevelopment[2489:60b] soundName = 'moof'
2013-09-22 11:03:40.757 MyAppUnderDevelopment[2489:60b] soundFileURLRef = file:///var/mobile/Applications/31785684-2EFA-4FEB-95F3-3A6B82B16A4A/MyAppUnderDevelopment.app/moof.caf
2013-09-22 11:03:45.356 MyAppUnderDevelopment[2489:60b] soundFileObject = 4101, status = 0
```

Any helpful ideas on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After preparing my question, I was running through my test sequence to ensure I had correctly recorded the steps I had taken. While single-stepping quickly through the code, I discovered that calling...

```
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(soundFileObject);
            AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundFileObject);
```

...in this way caused the `soundFileObject` to be disposed before the asynchronous sound had a chance to play. The short-term solution was to turn the soundFileObject into a retained property, and use lazy instantiation to create it as required.

Hope this helps someone else who may be banging their head against a wall.