# does OpenAL only work with caff format audio files

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, openal

I am making a game with sound effects and am using open al and using a .wav format audio file, but this does no play any sound.Does open al on iOS only allow caff files to be run and if so how can i convert wav audio files  to caff?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGpVlgy0PXM video helps you easy in converting to caff on mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OpenAL on iOS without any wrappers, it will only accept caff and wav as input. Also, you can check out this thread: [Converting audio to CAF format for playback on iPhone using OpenAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254080/converting-audio-to-caf-format-for-playback-on-iphone-using-openal)

But be careful, since OpenAl on iOs will not take ima4 compressed files directly as input!

Answer (score 0):

OpenAL like many audio rendering API's like Web Audio API require PCM audio as its only input format ---  any WAV,mp3 will need to be parsed upstream and fed into as audio buffer(s) of PCM audio